# Citrus-Cucumber: Can I run a single Cucumber Scenario?

Tags: intellij-idea, bdd, cucumber-junit, citrus-framework

I have a Cucumber feature file with a bunch of Scenarios to execute Citrus integration tests (**Citrus-Cucumber integration**). I can run all Scenarios at once in IntelliJ or through Maven.

Works perfect, but **is it possible to run a single Scenario** in IntelliJ or through Maven?

In IntelliJ I found a Cucumber plugin that gives me this option, but after fixing lots of `NoClassDefFound` errors with dependency tricks, it fails because it does not respect the Citrus project files such as `citrus-application.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to myself: Yes, I can.

According to the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#tags), it uses `tags` to (what a surprise) tag scenarios. Tags begin with the `@` symbol and one can set any number of tags on a Feature or Scenario.

Example:

```
@Test123
@Important
Scenario: My awesome Scenario
  Given ...
  When ...
  Then ...

@Test456
Scenario: My other Scenario
  Given ...
  When ...
  Then ...
```

With these tags in place, I can "select" scenarios to execute based on tags. For example to execute all important Scenarios I use the tag `@Important`.

```
cucumber --tags @Important
```

Since I execute my tests through a Citrus class, I have to pass the tags to execute in the `CucumberOptions` of my test class.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        strict = true,
        glue = { "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.step.runner.core" },
        plugin = { "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter" },
        tags = { "@Important" }
)
public class RunCucumberTests {
}
```

It is not super-convenient, to edit the test class metadata every time, but it works.

Comment: more documentation here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags